# prepareForSegue destination controller property not being set

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uistoryboardsegue

**Here's my prepareForSegue:**

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if ([segue.identifier isEqual:@"cameraToRollsSegue"]){
    ALRollsTableViewController *rollsTableViewController = (ALRollsTableViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
    Camera *c = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];
    NSLog(@"CAMERA FROM INSIDE PREPARE FOR SEQUE: %@", c);
    rollsTableViewController.selectedCamera = c;
}
```

}

**I verify that the camera is not null with NSLog:**

```
CAMERA FROM INSIDE PREPARE FOR SEQUE: <Camera: 0x8dc1400> (entity: Camera; id: 0x8dafba0 <x-coredata://A415F856-5F21-4F08-9CAB-4B2A023B55C3/Camera/p1> ;
```

**ALRollsTableViewController viewDidLoad:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog (@"ROLLS TABLE VIEW CONTROLLER : viewDidLoad!");
    NSLog(@"(selected camera = %@", self.selectedCamera);
 }
```

*results in:*

```
ROLLS TABLE VIEW CONTROLLER : viewDidLoad!
(selected camera = (null)
```

What might I be doing wrong here that the property is not being set?

---

UPDATE

With matt's help I've determined that the instance of my destination view controller in my prepareForSeque does not match the actual destination view controller:

```
rollsTableViewController FROM SEGUE: <ALRollViewController: 0x8d90bf0> 
rollsTableViewController FROM viewDidLoad in rollsTableViewController: <ALRollsTableViewController: 0x8c5ab00>
```

I don't know why this is the case or what to do to fix it.

Comment: +1 for good logging, well-posed question

Comment: It is possible that `viewDidLoad` is too soon. It might be called _before_ `prepareForSeque`! To test that idea, log inside `viewDidAppear:` instead and see...

Comment: thanks matt :) any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Also make sure `@property` declaration for `selectedCamera` is `strong`!

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) Camera *selectedCamera;

Comment: Good but do the other logging I suggested. Also, do test the "two instances" hypothesis just in case: log `rollsTableViewController` in `prepareForSeque` and `self` in `viewDidLoad` (and `viewDidAppear:`) to make sure they are the same instance.

Comment: (selected camera viewDidAppear = (null)

Comment: How is this segue triggered? What kind of segue is it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by how is it triggered

Comment: Storyboard Embed Seque

Comment: It sounds to me like this may be set up wrong in the storyboard. Do the 2nd set of logging I suggested to see if these are two different ALRollsTableViewController instances.

Comment: rollsTableViewController FROM SEGUE: <ALRollViewController: 0x8d90bf0>
rollsTableViewController FROM viewDidLoad in rollsTableViewController: <ALRollsTableViewController: 0x8c5ab00>

Comment: so yes, looks as though they are two different instances. What do I do to correct this?

Comment: I don't know because I don't know what you are trying to do, why you are even using an embed segue, how the storyboard is set up, and how you are causing the segue to happen.

Comment: is using an embed segue a bad thing?

Comment: Not if that's what you need. Do you understand what an embed segue _is_? Do you know how to use it and why?

Comment: I have a view which contains container view that contains a table view, i assume that why i need an embed segue?

Comment: You are not convincing me. If you need a table view why don't you just put a table view? You don't need the extra complication of a container view and a second view controller just for that.

Comment: I'm actually not convincing myself, I am fumbling my way thru this. I wanted my view to to have other components in it other than the table but it seemed "cleaner" to have a separate table controller rather than a kitchen sink controller if that makes any sense

Comment: There's no problem having a view with other components and a table view. The only restriction is that the table view is not managed by a UITableViewController. But that's no big deal.

Comment: Well I suppose its time for me to start over. Thanks so much for your time and patience with my naivete, I appreciate it matt

Comment: I'm happy to look at the existing project if you want me to try to figure out how it got incorrectly configured.

Comment: Really!? That would be great, although you'll probably want to hunt me down after seeing my attempt

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51847/discussion-between-matt-and-sam-luther)

Comment: Hello @matt - based on your suggestion I branched and re-thought what I was doing, it feels a lot cleaner to me and really cut down on my controllers. I was curious if you would have a look it. I don't have any particular problem, just interested in what you think. Of course I understand if you have no interest. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: As long as it's still working and you're happy with it, that's all that matters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Post-chat summary:***

Well, it was complicated! But basically you were saying this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if ([segue.identifier isEqual:@"cameraToRollsSegue"]){
    ALRollsTableViewController *rollsTableViewController = (ALRollsTableViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
    // ...
}
```

The problem was that `[segue destinationViewController]` was *not* an ALRollsTableViewController. Thus you were not talking to the instance you thought you were talking to, and you were not talking to an instance of the class you thought you were talking to.

The amazing thing is that your code didn't crash when it ran. You were saying this:

```
rollsTableViewController.selectedCamera = c;
```

But `rollsTableViewController` was not in fact an ALRollsTableViewController. You lied to the compiler when you cast incorrectly. Yet you didn't crash when that line ran. Why not? It's because you've got lots of classes with `@property selectedCamera`! So you were setting the property of a *different class*. But a property with that same name *did exist* in that class, so you didn't crash. Thus you didn't discover that this was the wrong class and the wrong instance.

Comment: So a way to avoid this in future is to do `NSAssert([viewController isKindOfClass:[TheClassIExpect class]], @"Unexpected class");` **before** any casts where this situation could possibly occur.

Comment: Going to go back at it today. You went above and beyond matt, I can't thank you enough for you help and direction!!!