# Objective C casting (id) vs. casting as an explicit class

Tags: objective-c

Often in objective C, you know an object is a kind of particular class, so you cast it into that class to continue using it:

```
NSObject *object;
NSString *string = (NSString *)object;
```

But, this has bothered me for some time - is there any advantage to writing out "NSString *" in that cast as opposed to the shorter (id):

```
NSObject *object;
NSString *string = (id)object;
```

I typically favor verbose Objective-C because the language is designed for readability, but I can't figure out any advantage of being verbose in this case.

Comment: In the above situation it basically doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Added: The main question is which is clearer and less error-prone, given your environment and overall coding style (and any team conventions, etc).  (And whether or not you do a runtime check to guarantee that the object is the expected type has no real connection to which style you choose.)

Comment: @HotLicks - I tend to agree with you - there is not much real distinction. The question of which is best is probably a matter of taste, so I am hoping to see what people's tastes are.

Comment: @HotLicks - This question needs an answer, and I think your thoughts have been the best. Do you want to put in an actual answer that sums up your comments?

Comment: Nah, I don't do answers.  (Much to the consternation of folks in Meta.)

Comment: Haha. Well, its not hard to see that you have actually done 1477 answers!

Answer (score 7):

Anything you can do to give the compiler more precise **and accurate** information about the types in play, the more the compiler can validate your code.  The `id` type basically means *this thing responds to any method I've ever seen declared` to the compiler wherein a specific cast narrows it to only the methods that class supports.

In general, casts are to be avoided.   They *generally* indicate poor architecture.   Not always, though, as they are oft unavoidable when dynamically generating UI or parsing JSON.

In that case, a construct that boils down to this is oft helpful:

```
NSObject *object;
NSAssert((!object) || [object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]);
NSString *string = (NSString *)object;
```

That forces verification of the *I know better than the compiler* to runtime.  (And, yes, it explicitly allows `nil` to pass through in this case.... your specific needs may vary.)

Comment: I like your answer, assuming it is true (which all bbum answers are, right?), but does the compiler really have more information in either case, since both declare 'string' as NSString?

Comment: @RichardVenable - The compiler has essentially the same information in both cases.

Comment: @RichardVenable The important thing here is the assert, which is checked _at runtime_. We just had an elaborate case of this, here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23419522/341994 The OP was casting, of necessity (`segue.destinationViewController` is an `id`) - but, unbeknownst, he was casting falsely (he was _assuming_ he knew the true class, but in fact he'd made a mistake and he didn't). The assert, as someone points out in a comment, would have caught this.

Comment: @matt - But the use of an assertion is totally separate from the cast "style" -- either "style" would work equally well with an assertion.

Comment: @HotLicks `id` would allow any method from any class (as long as the compiler has seen the declaration. `NSString*` restricts the scope of methods to those declared via `NSString` (including superclasses).  The assertion validates the cast.  The cast to a specific type enables the compiler to validate subsequent method calls.  So, yes, there is a difference between casting to `id` and casting to the specific type of `NSString*`.

Comment: @bbum - But in both of the above cases he's immediately assigning to an `NSString*` pointer.

Comment: @HotLicks Yup. You're right.  I missed that. Yes, in that case, it makes little difference and makes me what a variant of the `auto` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is not using down-casting at all by developing more thought-out architecture.
Constructions like this `NSString *string = (NSString *)object;` simply hide compiler warning and don't make any run-time casting.
But there are some situations when compiler can't know what kind of object is returned by method. For example: `[NSDictionary valueForKey:]` returns object of `id` type that is reference to object of any class. It is so because `NSDictionary` could contain any objects of any class and Objective C doesn't support templates where you could provide class of objects that collection will contain due initialisation.
In such situations usually used constructions like this:

```
id object = dictionary[key];
NSString *string = object;
```

Update:
However if consider situation when method returns object of kind `NSObject` that is really `NSString` then for compiler it doesn't matter what kind of casting you use: `(id)` or `(NSString *)` . But logically it's better to use `(NSString *)` as it shows kind of object that you expect. I mean that it is more clear for person who will read your code.

Comment: The casting I am referring to is different from the dictionary object example you gave. Objects returned by the dictionary are already of type 'id'. The use case I am referring to is unfortunately common out of necessity in Cocoa. For instance, when you create Storyboard with a UINavigationController and a root view controller - UINavigationController.topViewController is a UIViewController, but you must usually cast it as whatever subclass you are using to continue.

Comment: You didn't really say anything.  In both cases you're starting with a "generic" type and telling the compiler what you think it is.  The only reason for picking one version vs the other is clarity of the code, and I can see arguments both ways for that.

Comment: @HotLicks, "The only reason for picking one version vs the other is clarity of the code, and I can see arguments both ways for that" - that is really the argument I am looking for. I wasn't asking about how or why I should verify that I am using the right class (I completely agree with everything being said on that subject).

Comment: @Visput, I come from that perspective you mentioned in your update: "But logically it's better to use (NSString *) as it shows kind of object that you expect", but more recently I lean to it not making any difference in the readability, since the same exact line explicitly states that you intend it to be an NSString ("NSString *string =").

Comment: @RichardVenable - Yep, it might be different if the cast and the assignment were somehow separated, or the type of the assigned-to pointer was not patently obvious.  But using `(id)` has the advantage of being concise (important if the "real" type is `MyReallyReallyReallyReallyLongClassName*` instead of `NSString*`).  So there are considerations both ways.

Comment: @RichardVenable, my logic is simple: If I expect `NSString *` - I cast to `(NSString *)`. I don't use `(id)` or `(NSMutableString *)`(as it also will hide compiler warning) because it is not that type that I really expect.

Comment: declaring in a way that the compiler knows what is stored in dictionary helps also. see `NSDictionary<NSString*,id>` vs `NSDictionary<NSString*,id<NSObject>>` vs `NSDictionary<NSString*,id<MyClassProtocol>>` vs `NSDictionary<NSString*,MyClass*>`