# segue.destinationViewController is nil when presenting UINavigationController modal

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboardsegue

I have an `UICollectionView` and when the user presses a cell, I present another view controller in a `UINavigationController` modally using a storyboard.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"editBookIPad"
                                      sender:indexPath];
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
                 sender:(id)sender
{
    // Did not include code for other segues, but I check which is the current one properly
    UINavigationController *dest = segue.destinationViewController; // This is nil!
    dest.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    DetailsViewController *detailsVC = (id)[dest topViewController];
    detailsVC.stack = self.stack;
    detailsVC.editingMode = 1;
    detailsVC.bookToEdit = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:sender];
    [self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:sender
                                        animated:YES];
}
```

[image: Storyboard]

**Now, my problem is that `segue.desinationViewController` returns `nil` (as the comment in the code snippet says).**

Just for debugging, I changed the `UINavigationController` to another view controller and I had no problem. I don't know if changing from modal to push as transition style will help since it's impossible to push a `UINavigationController` (a crash happens that says it is so).

I cleaned the project and the build folder and restarted my computer (and hence Xcode).

This is what it looks like when running the app:

[image: Screenshot of problem]

When searching for similar problems I found nothing about this. Most other questions were about properties being set on the destination view controller being nil (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413884/prepareforsegue-destination-controller-property-not-being-set)).

I use Xcode 5.1.1 and have iOS 7.0 as development target.

**Edit1**

The same problem happens in all parts of my app now (everywhere a `UINavigationController` is presented modally). *However*, it only happens on some occasions, but every time `segue.destinationViewController` is still `nil`.

**Edit2**

I replaced the `prepareForSegue` code with this (doing it manually):

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard"
                                                     bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navCon = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AllBooksVCDetails"]; // The problematic navigation controller
navCon.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
BKSBookDetailsViewController *detailsVC = (id)[navCon topViewController];
detailsVC.stack = self.stack;
detailsVC.editingMode = 1;
detailsVC.bookToEdit = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[self presentViewController:navCon
                   animated:YES
                 completion:nil];
[self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath
                                    animated:YES];
```

And this works. So I think the problem lies in the storyboard somehow.

Answer (score 14):

I had same problem when embedding the viewcontroller inside a NavigationController.

```swift
 override public func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let nextViewController = destinationVC.viewControllers[0] as! SecondViewController

        nextViewController.someProperty = someValue
    }
```

This link helps me:

https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/06/02/access-sub-controllers-from-a-uinavigationcontroller-in-swift/

Answer (score 7):

I also encountered this problem using swift, but after 1 hour, observed that instead of **segue**.destinationViewController I used **sender**.destinationViewController that messed all things. 
Are you sure you are using segue not sender?

Comment: I checked my code and I was using **segue**. Thanks for the answer though

Answer (score 3):

Problem is when embedding UIViewController inside a UINavigationController. A variant of S. Matsepura's answer where "ShowView" is the identifier of the segue (if you have more than one):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowView" {
        if let nc = segue.destination as? UINavigationController, let vc = nc.topViewController as? MyViewController {
            vc.var = "value"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and I think the issue is embedding the viewcontroller inside a NavigationController. As soon as I removed the navigation controller, prepareForSegue worked as expected and segue.destinationViewController started returning the proper viewController class.

Just wanted to add this as info.

So my problem was segue.destinationViewController had nil in it to be passed to self.preboardingViewController:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "GoToPreBoarding" {


        self.preboardingViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? PreBoardingViewController
        self.preboardingViewController?.myShiftViewController = self
    }
}
```

So in swift, I solved the problem pretty much the same way as yours, getting the navigationcontroller topviewController threw me off for a bit. Here is my solution:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "PreBoarding", bundle: nil)
        let navCon = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PreBoardingNavigation") as! UINavigationController
        navCon.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FormSheet
        self.preboardingViewController = navCon.topViewController as? PreBoardingViewController
        self.preboardingViewController?.myShiftViewController = self
        self.presentViewController(navCon, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure, in the Destination ViewController class on the Storyboard, you enable `Inherit Module From Target` checkbox, under the Class's Identity Inspector